# Troubles adjusting ticks and gridlines on Matlab 2014b

Tags: matlab, plot, grid

I'm working on an assignment in which we need to plot curves with gridlines at specific points but I can't figure out how to do it.

This is what I got so far:

```
figure,
plot(x1,y1)
xlim([0 20]);
ylim([-0.5 1]);
ax = gca;    
ax.XTickMode = 'manual';    
ax.XTick = [0:5:20];
grid on;
```

And, on the picture below, is what I needed:

[image]

Comment: Running the above code gives me that picture.  However, I'm using R2013a so setting the properties of the figure using dot notation is not supported yet as it is in R2014, but these are the commands I used: `x1 = 0:0.01:20;
y1 = exp(-x1/4).*sin(x1);
plot(x1,y1);
set(gca, 'XTick', 0:5:20, 'XTickMode', 'manual');
grid on;` As such, I can't reproduce your error.  Can you specify what your problem is?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It just doesn't work when I run the code :(

Comment: Are there any packages or whatever I need to install in order to use this? The "set" command won't work (error) but when I use dot notation it compiles and runs but the result is not as expected.

Comment: As I said I used R2013a. R2014 switched to using dot notation rendering the `set` method deprecated. Try the answer below. It makes sense.

Comment: I'm actually using 2014a, not 2014b... silly me. What should the command be for this version?

Comment: Read my previous comment to you.... Carefully. Good luck!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If one answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it, by clicking the green checkmark on the left to indicate the system that you're happy ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to set the YTicks as well.

```
figure
x1 = 0:0.01:20; 
y1 = exp(-x1/4).*sin(x1); plot(x1,y1);
plot(x1,y1)
xlim([0 20]);
ylim([-0.5 1]);
ax = gca;    

ax.XTick = [0:5:20];
ax.YTick = [-0.4:0.2:1];
xlabel('$$f(x)$$','interpreter','latex')
ylabel('$$x$$','interpreter','latex')
title('$$f(x) = \exp{(-\frac{x}{4})} \cdot \sin(x)$$','interpreter','latex')
grid on;
```

[image]